# Issue with sending POST form data with PHP : cURL

Tags: php, forms, curl, post

Below are 2 pieces of code whose result should be identical (at least I would like). This result consists in logging in to a website in one click by sending a form.
The HTML one works well and allows me to connect perfectly.
The PHP one gives me a hard time. The PHP/cURL one runs correctly, I mean if I change Login/Password variables, the server sends me back "wrong user/password", but if I send the correct Login/Password, the server turns in deep meditation and never answers me.

Do any of you have any suggestions for this behaviour ? (I certainly would have missed something...).
Thanks

**«AutoConnect.HTM»:**

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () { document.getElementById('autolog').submit(); }
</script>
<body>
<form id="autolog" action="https://website.com/account/logon" method="post">
  <input name="Login" value="User">
  <input name="Password" value="Pass">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**«AutoConnect.PHP»:**

```
<?php
 $url = 'https://website.com/account/logon';
 $postinfo = http_build_query(array(
         'Login'    => 'User',
         'Password' => 'Pass'
         ));
 $client = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)';
 $header = array(
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'Accept: */*',
        'Accept-Language: fr-FR',
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length: '.(strlen($postinfo))
        );
 $options = array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $header,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $client,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
        CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $postinfo,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url
        );
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
 $result = curl_exec($ch); 
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After wandering the web for hours, I did it!
Solution was there on stackoverflow, but I was missing a key word.
The server I'm trying to connect to is an «ASP» one with ASPXAUTH.
The use of cookies had to be integrated.
I give you here the final PHP code:

```
<?php
$url   = 'https://website.com/account/logon';
$post  = http_build_query(array(
         'Login'    => 'User',
         'Password' => 'Pass'
         ));
$client = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)';
$ckfile= 'MyCookie.txt'; 
$options1= array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,   // accepts all certificats
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $client,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => $ckfile, // cookie needed 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,    // returns string
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
        );
$options2= array(
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => $ckfile, // cookie used
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $post    // form datas
        );
$ch      = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch,$options1);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_setopt_array($ch,$options2);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $output;
?>
```